# Python midi out to FruityLoops Studio

Tags: python, max, midi

im working on a project
and i want to create a virtual midi input with python to flstudio (fruityloops)
i have googled a bit but all the modules i could find was about creating midi files which is not my issue.

so what module should i use for midi i/o with python?

Comment: Step 1.  Search.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+midi  All of these are potentially duplicates of your question.

Comment: im not looking for a way to output midi files :S :S
i wanna create virtual(fake) midi input to use in flstudio software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahmet, I recommend MIDI Yoke for this.  Building a virtual MIDI device driver is no easy task, and it isn't something you'll be doing with Python.

http://www.midiox.com/myoke.htm

**Edit 2011:** Some things have changed in the last year.  I recommend using Tobias Erichsen's driver, which allows you to create virtual ports and send data to them.  If you can use a DLL, you can use his driver.

The info is here:  http://www.tobias-erichsen.de/rtpMIDI.html

Contact him for the API.

Answer (score 2):

I was just looking to accomplish your exact task and came across the python ["mido library"](https://mido.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). From this page you see:

```
import mido
output = mido.open_output()
output.send(mido.Message('note_on', note=60, velocity=64))
```

I believe this assumes that a default device is set however, so you may need to run:

```
names = mido.get_output_names()
print(names)
```

To see what midi devices are available to output too. Once you know what your device name is you can do:

```
output = mido.open_output(names[indexOfYourDeviceHere])
output.send(mido.Message('note_on', note=60, velocity=64))
```

Now, how does this interface with FL Studio? I have installed [LoopBe1 Virtual Midi Driver](http://nerds.de/en/loopbe1.html), and so when I run the above code the LoopBe Internal Midi device shows up. Similarly, in FL Studio I have enabled the LoopBe Internal MIDI device. Thus, when your python program writes to the device FL Studio reads it as midi input!

Alas, I did have some trouble setting up mido on my windows machine and so I thought I would give you a pointer. In order to read or write to midi devices you need to have a "mido backend" installed. On linux I simply followed the instructions on their installation page to install portmidi and it worked great.

However, for windows, I was having LOTS of trouble trying to work with portmidi or the other option. I finally decided to install pygame (3rd option) for windows and then set that as my backend using:

```
mido.set_backed("mido.backends.pygame")
```

Then everything worked fine on windows. You can find pygame for windows as well as the mido installation page easily by googling. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Hi Sheun, welcome to SO. Would you mind editing your answer to expand it, especially to indicate to the asker why this particular library might solve their problem, and how they could set it up? Answers here are generally expected to have a bit more substance than just directing someone to an arbitrary library. Thanks!